# SQL Server Reporting Services Calendar-like Report

Tags: reporting-services, calendar, ssrs-tablix

I'm writing a report to represent the schedule of work for a given customer. The report has to resemble a calendar, and show work orders that span multiple days as a spanning bar similar to Outlook.

I made the calendar fairly quickly using two tablix controls. My problem now, and the reason for this question, is representing the spanning events.

Currently, I render (using test data of course): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxqyo.png

I'm determining a lot of things in the stored procedure (how many days a given event spans, which day that given event is) and manipulating the background and borders of each cell so that they *appear* to be merged. This works alright with the exception of the cell text: it's cut off if the name of the event is too long.

I've done some research, and it appears that you just can't programmatically merge cells. I think my best hope might be somehow allowing the name of the event to overflow (sort of how you would see a cell overflow in Excel).

Is that possible?

For reference, we're using SQL Server 2012, but I'm using BIDS via VS2008 to make the report. It's a run-of-the-mill RDL report. I'm not against buying a control that would do this for me instead.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think that's possible. The solution would increase the cell size.

Comment: I was worried that'd be the case. I'll probably have to make this web based which, truth be told, I wanted to do from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out another solution that satisfied the requirements laid out by my superiors.

The short of it: I created a simple HTML calendar populated with the events. I then render the page as an image (like a screenshot) and use the Image Control in SSRS to load it. The SSRS report passes its parameters to the webpage as a query string.

For the curious who find this question through web searches, here's the method I use to create the bitmap:

```
private Bitmap CreateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap screenshot = null;

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (var browser = new WebBrowser())
                {
                    browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

                    browser.Width = width;
                    browser.Height = height;

                    browser.Navigate(url);

                    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }

                    screenshot = new Bitmap(width, height);
                    browser.DrawToBitmap(screenshot, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
                }
            });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        return screenshot;
    }
```

I call it from within the controller as so:

```
public void Action()
    {
        var model = new ViewModel
            {
                StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 6, 30),
                EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 8, 10),
                OpsId = ####
            };


        var url = Url.Action("ActionThatCallsCalendar", "Controller", new { area = "Area", viewModel = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model) }, Request.Url.Scheme);


        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.Clear();

        var screenshot = CreateScreenshot(url, 1400, 1050);
        screenshot.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        Response.Flush();
    }
```